# Swift optionals OptionalValue

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

i want to take the dimension of my view and assign it to my scrollView. This is my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    var screenRect:CGRect = self.window?.bounds

    var bigRect = screenRect
    bigRect.size.width *= 2.0
    bigRect.size.height *= 2.0

    var scrollView:UIScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: screenRect)
    self.window?.addSubview(scrollView)

    var hypnoView:View = View(frame: bigRect)
    scrollView.addSubview(hypnoView)

    scrollView.contentSize = bigRect.size

    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


    return true
}
```

When i write this xcode  `var screenRect:CGRect = self.window?.bounds` Xcode give me an error to OptionalValue....i?m getting lost with theese optionals. 
how to translate the old objective-c line

```
CGRect screenRect = self.window.bounds
```

into swift?

Answer (score 4):

`var screenRect = self.window!.bounds` would work for you.

Please note that your app *will crash* on this line if `self.window` is nil, as this is what the `!` operator does: unwraps the optional, crashes if it's `nil`.

In this case, the variable's type is `UIWindow?`, meaning that it could have a `UIWindow`, or could be `nil`. If you want to get access to the `UIWindow` object, you have to unwrap it. In this particular scenario I'm suggesting `!` for a specific reason. Keep reading:

Yes, `!` here will make your code crash if `self.window` was to be `nil`. So why use this? By doing this, you're making an assertion that you expect `self.window` to have been set, it being `nil` is an error condition, and you *want* your app to crash loudly and visibly. You'd see the crash, and look elsewhere in your code to fix the actual error. Perhaps you didn't connect the `IBOutlet` for the window in Interface Builder, or something else.

Referring to the original post, the problem with saying `self.window?.bounds` is this: when you write that, you're saying "try unwrapping `window` -- if it's nil, no big deal, just return `nil` instead of trying to get `bounds`. But the type of `screenRect` is `CGRect` (without the question mark), meaning that it *cannot* be `nil`. So, your code is not compiling.

If you really wanted `screenRect` to be maybe-nil, you'd need to declare `screenRect` as `CGRect?` meaning that it could have a `CGRect`, or could be `nil`.

Finally, please read this article to better understand optionals: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-06-20-interesting-swift-features.html

Comment: any good tutorial on the Optional? i read some and i got what they are for, but it never comes to my mind when it's time to use them

Comment: There's a big mistake in your answer: you suggest to use the forced unwrapping `!`, but then you say: _"the window could be nil"_. If an optional can be nil, using the forced unwrapping causes a runtime exception. Optional binding or explicit check for nil should be used instead.

Comment: @Antonio: Please read the discussion above with the answer by nhgrif. In this case you specifically *want* your code to loudly crash when `self.window` is `nil`.

Comment: The point is that if somebody reads your answer only, he might think that force unwrapping is the correct way to unwrap any optional. I just suggest that you modify your answer to make that explicit.

Comment: Sure, I went ahead and added more detail that'll hopefully help others.

Comment: @Marco, "when to use them" is a great question. To use them effectively, you have to reason what conditions you want to hold at each line of code. Question to ask: "If this were `nil`, is it an error?" Sometimes it is, and you want your code to crash, indicating developer error. Example: you forgot to connect the `IBOutlet`. Sometimes it is, but you don't want the code to crash -- it's an error that you want to handle gracefully, displaying something to the user. Example: connection to the server failed. Hope this helps a bit!

Answer (score 2):

The best option in this specific case is probably, as DPlusV suggest in the first line of his answer:

```
var screenRect: CGRect = self.window!.bounds
```

This will crash if `self.window` is `nil`, but given that in this specific scenario, we're in `didFinishLaunching`, if `self.window` is somehow `nil`, we've got some other much bigger problem.

There are two other approaches to Swift's optionals however, and which of the three options you should use is situation dependent.

---

We can change the first line to something more like this:

```
var screenRect: CGRect = self.window?.bounds ?? CGRectZero
```

And it will work.  In the case that the `window` property of `self` is `nil`, then `screenRect` will just be created as a rect with an origin of (0,0) and a size of (0,0).  This will assure us that `screenRect` is always initialized, never nil, and that all of the following code always executes.

---

Otherwise, if we want to let the following code only execute if we're able to get a rect out of `self.window?.bounds`, then we might try something more like this:

```
if let screenRect = self.window?.bounds {
    var bigRect = screenRect

    // etc., all the rest of your code
}

return true
```

Comment: While this answer would fix the immediate problem, I don't recommend it in this scenario. In the `nil` case, the novice developer will then spend hours wondering why their rect is zero'd. Code should be opinionated: the developer should decide if at the end of the day they want something to be sometimes `nil` nor not. Your approach just swallows the problem instead of forcing the developer to write correct code.

Comment: My answer offers two approaches.  Truly, `screenRect` probably should be a `nil`-able `CGRect`.  Instead, we should take the `if let` approach rather than then checking it for `nil` every step of the way after.

Comment: It's a matter for setting expectations. For example, if you're reading name, age, and occupation from the database, and occupation may be not set, it's totally appropriate to use your approach. It's valid to not have the occupation there. But in this case, if `self.window` was `nil`, there'd be a bug and they'd be be silently hiding it.

Comment: Please read my entire, current answer.  At every point, I mention that you should use this approach or that depend on what results you want, and I make it clear what the results would be.  My new edits make that far more clear.  But if `self.window` is `nil` in `didFinishLaunching`, the bug isn't so "silent"... the fact that we initialized `screenRect` to (0,0,0,0) is the LEAST of our problems if `window` is nil... which is basically impossible in `didFinishLaunching`...

Comment: Thanks for being thorough, and I upvoted your answer.

Comment: I think when choosing the approach to use it's useful to keep in mind the likely correct scenario. Essentially, let's say `window` was nil. What do you want to happen? Do you want the rect to *ever* be zero? What state does that represent? Do you want half of the code to not run/fail in confusing ways? Or do you want an obvious crash? Ending thread here :)

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing how window actually could be nil here.